# Ruby on Rails - $ rails server fails because uglifier gem could not be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm starting my first project on Ruby and the tutorial I'm following has me using rails.  When I try to run `$ rails server` I get an error that says: Could not find gem `uglifier (>=1.3.0) x86-mingw32` in the gems available on this machine.

I had this error with a few other gems, and I was able to fix it by simply doing the `gem install` of the gem at hand, but this one is giving me errors.  These errors started to appear after I tried to install the dev kit for the first time.  When I try `$ gem install uglifier` I get a large mess of errors that can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF2mJ.png).

I am running on a Windows 8 tablet.  While I realize Ubuntu is the preference for this situation, I'm trying to make the best with what I'm given.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I only see warnings in the image you are providing. In order to help, we are going to have to see the error that is generated.

Answer (score 4):

1. Locate your Gemfile {C:\Users[your name]\Desktop\sample_app}
2. In line 1, change https to http {source 'http://rubygems.org'}
3. Save changes in Gemfile
4. In your Gitbash, type "bundle install" and hit Enter

Answer (score 3):

I was following these instructions: [Installing Ruby, Rails and Rubymine in Ubuntu 14.04](http://daharper.com/2014/04/23/installing-ruby-rails-and-rubymine-in-ubuntu-14-04/)

and had the same problem when I got to testing the rails server. 
while creating the new demo:

> abc@ubuntu:~/rails_demo$ rails new demo
>
> An error occurred while installing uglifier (2.5.3), and Bundler
>   cannot continue.Make sure that `gem install uglifier -v '2.5.3'`
>   succeeds before bundling.
>            run  bundle exec spring binstub --al

I did not catch the above until I attempted to run the server

```
abc@ubuntu:~/rails_demo/demo$ rails server
Could not find gem 'uglifier (>= 1.3.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
abc@ubuntu:~/rails_demo/demo$ bundle install uglifier
ERROR: "bundle install" was called with arguments ["uglifier"]
Usage: "bundle install [OPTIONS]"
```

running the following fixed the problem:

> gem install uglifier -v '2.5.3'
>
> bundle exec spring binstub --all

hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Check if your Gemfile has the following gem

```
gem 'uglifier'
```

If the Gem is not present add it to your Gemfile. Sometimes it turns out that your Gemfile.lock has the dependency but you might have commented the Gem in Gemfile.

I you already have the gem in Gemfile run bundle install and check if the bundler is installing the uglifier gem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Windows 10, I fix the "gem install uglifier" command
the path was like this: `C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ parent_folder \ name_project> gem install uglifier`

Answer (score 0):

** For Windows **

Install Nodejs.
If it's already installed add it's path in Environment Variables

Variable Name: Path 
Location : Where node is installed (C:\Program Files\nodejs)

Re run The command rails server

Answer (score 0):

Run 'bundle install'
and then 'bundle update'
this worked for me

Answer (score -2):

install nodejs

```
apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: The OP is on windows.

Comment: unfortunately op is on windows, for ubuntu it's working.