# ruby on rails uglifier error on server start up WINDOWS 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, uglifier

so im new to this and im trying to star my localhost server for rails v5 on win10 i have looked around and cant figer it out

i put this code in`

```
bundler exec rails server
```

then i get this

```
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
Backtrace for gem load error is:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.1.13/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.1.13/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
C:/Sites/test_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/test_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

pls help

Comment: uglifier issue occurs usually if nodejs is not installed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails - $ rails server fails because uglifier gem could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951412/ruby-on-rails-rails-server-fails-because-uglifier-gem-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install NodeJS, please check out https://nodejs.org/en/download/

But if you want to keep developing with Rails on Windows, you should check the WSL https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/commandline/wsl/install_guide