# Rails server could not find uglifier in GemFile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Just got on learning ruby on rails a few days ago, I am trying to start my first rails project and anytime I try starting the rails server using the command `rails server`, I get this error:

> could not find gem 'uglifier (>=1.3.0) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your GemFile.

I started the project with these commands:

```
rails new hello_world
cd hello_world
rails server
```

I have run the `bundle install` and yet I still get the error.
Is there any way to fix this or is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Are you using the latest rails version and what is the content of your Gemfile? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951412/ruby-on-rails-rails-server-fails-because-uglifier-gem-could-not-be-found

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but i have fixed it by downloading the gem from github

Answer (score 1):

Try add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'uglifier', '~> 4.2'
```

and then **bundle install**

Hope it helps.

Comment: so maybe try this: `gem install uglifier` and then `bundle exec spring binstub --all`

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
gem install bundle
```

Then

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

try manually reinstalling.

```
gem cleanup uglifier
gem install uglifier
```